# Android Studio - Parsing with jsoup throws error (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to data_mine a table from a website, store it into an `ArrayList<String>`and view it on a `ListView` layout. Every time I run the program I get this error.

```
04-29 23:52:57.122 20095-20095/com.example.user.datamining E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.project.datamining, PID: 20095
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.datamining/com.example.user.DataMining}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.jsoup.select.Elements org.jsoup.nodes.Document.select(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.jsoup.select.Elements org.jsoup.nodes.Document.select(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

This is my code:

```
package com.example.user.datamining;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataMining extends AppCompatActivity {
    Document doc;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_mining);

        Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://thewebsite.html").get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        downloadThread.start();

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
            Elements table = doc.select("table"); 
            Elements rows = table.select("tr");

            for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) { 
                org.jsoup.nodes.Element row =  rows.get(i);
                Elements cols = row.select("td");

                list.add(cols.get(i).text());


                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.datalayout, list);
                ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dataListView);
                view.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: `doc` is `null` when you call `select()` on it, because the `downloadThread` you started right before that has not completed yet, and that's presumably where you initialize it.

Comment: So what should I do? @MikeM.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you posted the thread right there. Didn't see it. Gimme a minute, and I'll reorganize your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting a separate thread to perform the download, and initialize `doc`. This thread runs asynchronously, so `doc` is still `null` when you call `select()` on it right after starting the thread.

Move the parsing code to after the download in the thread's `run()` method, and use the `Activity`'s `runOnUiThread()` method after the parse to set the `ListView`'s `Adapter`, since you can't touch `View`s directly from that download thread.

```
private Document doc;
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreat(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_mining);

    Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://thewebsite.html").get();

                Elements table = doc.select("table"); 
                Elements rows = table.select("tr");

                for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) { 
                    org.jsoup.nodes.Element row =  rows.get(i);
                    Elements cols = row.select("td");

                    list.add(cols.get(i).text());
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            setListAdapter();
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    downloadThread.start();
}

private void setListAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.datalayout, list);
    ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dataListView);
    view.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just finished what I wanted to do with that class and everything is working accordingly!!